# ServiceMix: ESB or "OSGI Application Server"?

Tags: osgi, integration, esb, apache-servicemix

For an integration project I am working on, I started looking at java integration technologies/ESBs. Mule and ServiceMix seemed to fit my needs. I chose ServiceMix but found my self using Camel exclusively (inside ServiceMix). And then this question arose:

Is serviceMix an ESB (which I thought it was) or an Application server like Spring DM Server?

Or may be it is an Application Server fine tuned for Integration?
Sorry if my question feels silly :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Karaf is the OSGi container, Servicemix is built on top of Karaf and has out of the box support for ActiveMQ, Camel, CXF, Ode, etc (via pre-installed features, bundles and configuration).

Long story short, Camel provides the integration/EIP backbone, but OSGi (Karaf or Servicemix) is a container to deploy it in.  Camel can also be deployed in other ways as well: in a webapp (Tomcat, etc), in ActiveMQ, standalone, with Spring, etc.

I asked a similar questions as to whether to use Karaf or Servicemix...

[Apache Karaf vs. Servicemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930236/apache-karaf-vs-servicemix)